# How to call method from another controller to helper function?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter I would like to use helper, my helper function would be need to call another methods that belong to other controllers. Do I possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Helpers are not written in an Object Oriented format. They are simple, procedural functions. Each helper function performs one specific task, with no dependence on other functions.

So if your helper function would need to call another method of a controller, then there is no point in creating it as a helper function.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: So if as my wanted, any solution in codeIgniter that i can use?

Comment: you cant call another codeigniter function from helper, but if you want it, then you can make a http call to that method of controller, through curl.